# SQL count multiple cells as combination

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL table which shows case number and their value, the case number always appear 2 cases in a group, I want to count how many the combinations with same case number appearing in the table. Be ware the order could be different, see case A and C, both of them should be count as the same combination.

```
case  value

A     1992

A     1956

B     2000

B     2001

C     1956

C     1992
```

**The goal is to get the total number of each combination, so the output format doesn't matter. One of expected result:**

```
Seq  value   frequency

1    1992    2

1    1956    2

2    2000    1

2    2001    1
```

**What about if there are 3 cases as a combination?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works with any number of values for any case. It only increment frequency count when cases have the same number of values and each one have a match, no matter in which order.

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
    ([Case] varchar(1), [Value] int)
;

INSERT INTO #Table1
    ([Case], [Value])
VALUES
    ('A', 1992),    ('A', 1956),    ('A', 1997),    ('B', 2000),    ('B', 2001),    ('C', 1956),
    ('C', 1992),     ('C', 1997),   /*('C',1993),*/    ('D', 2005),    ('D', 2008),    ('E', 1956),
    ('E', 1992) ,    ('F', 1956),    ('F', 1992),        ('G', 1956),    ('G', 1992)  ;

--Query
select min(a.[Case]) [Case], [Values], count(*) frequency
from (
    SELECT  t.[Case],
             stuff(
                    (
                        select  ',' + cast (t1.[Value] as varchar(20))
                        from    #table1 t1
                        where   t1.[Case] = t.[Case]
                        order by t1.[Value] 
                        for xml path('')
                    ),1,1,'') [Values]
    FROM    #table1 t
    GROUP BY t.[Case]
    )a
group by [Values]
order by [Case]
```

Result whith values sorted in ascending order

```html
Case Values frequency
A 1956,1992,1997 2
B 2000,2001 1
D 2005,2008 1
E 1956,1992 3
```

Comment: Thank you. The original my question is that the data will constantly appear 3 times together. your query can handle more complicated contition. This solved my problem.

Comment: I really want to pivot the table so that I can easily use "distinct" to count. Is any way to change the data to 4 columns? It will shows Case, Value1, Value2, Value3

Comment: Modify your question with sample data and expected results, I'll see it later.

Comment: I have tick this one as solution, and vote it, however, you won't see it because I am a beginner user.

Comment: @paddywide HI, add new data samples and expected results. I'll see it later

Comment: Hi, @Horaciux, Since this is different question, can you look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45496453/sql-pivot-table-with-three-rows-as-a-group?

Answer (score 0):

Data sample, SQL Server 2014

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([case] varchar(1), [value] int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([case], [value])
VALUES
    ('A', 1992),
    ('A', 1956),
    ('B', 2000),
    ('B', 2001),
    ('C', 1956),
    ('C', 1992)
;
```

Query

```
select dense_rank() over (ORDER BY min(a.[case])) seq,  a.value, count(*) freq 
from table1 a left join table1 b
    on a.value=b.value and a.[case]<>b.[case]
group by a.value 
order by a.value
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/40a87/3

Comment: The result issn't correct, one of frequency is 9000, however the total row of my table is only 1500

Comment: could you add more data sample with special cases?

Comment: If you look at SQLFiddle example, I added more data in the form you share and worked fine. Need to know other combinations that can break this logic

Comment: I just want to count the total of the combination. Shouldn't use rank function.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly as you post expected results, but respond on what you just request in the previous comment.

```
select min, max,  count (*) freq
from (
  select a.[case] [case], min(a.value) min, max(a.value) max
  from table1 a      
  group by a.[case]) b
 group by min, max
 order by min, max
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/40a87/18

Comment: This works in a tricky way. But it doesn't work with 3 or more values as a combination. Thanks anyway, it did solve my question. If there are 3 or more values as a combination, can you work it out?

Comment: You said data came in pairs `the case number always appear 2 cases in a group`, now you say that can be a greater number? Is it a fixed number? Could you add more data samples?