# SQL Pivot table with 3 rows as a group

Tags: sql, pivot

I am using SQL2012. I have the following SQL table which shows case number and their value. The case number always appears 3 cases as a group. Can you help me to pivot the table? The number of case number is more than a thousand.

```
case  value
A     1992
A     1956
A     2007
B     2000
B     2001
B     1990
C     2000
C     1956
C     1817
```

Expected result:

```
Case  value1   value2   value3
A    1992      1956     2007
B    2000      2001     1990
C    2000      1956     1817
```

Comment: What query are you writing?

Comment: @Gaurang Deshpande I don't know how to write this query, that's why I post here.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (The answer will perhaps be product specific.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` and apply conditional aggregation:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        Rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [case] ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM Tbl
)
SELECT
    [case],
    value1 = MAX(CASE WHEN Rn = 1 THEN value END),
    value2 = MAX(CASE WHEN Rn = 2 THEN value END),
    value3 = MAX(CASE WHEN Rn = 3 THEN value END)
FROM Cte
GROUP BY [case];
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](http://rextester.com/AJKB90532)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I'll address this question as a follow up on your previous one, where you need to count the frequency of cases that share the same values regardless the order.
[Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45363037/sql-count-multiple-cells-as-combination/45425122?noredirect=1#comment77954236_45425122)

```
declare  @Table1 TABLE
    ([case] varchar(1), [value] int)
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    ([case], [value])
VALUES
    ('A', 1992),    ('A', 1956),    ('A', 1986),
    ('B', 2000),    ('B', 2001),    ('B', 2003),
    ('C', 1986),    ('C', 1956),    ('C', 1992),
    ('D', 2005),    ('D', 2008),    ('D', 2002),
    ('E', 1954),    ('E', 1956),    ('E', 1992),
    ('G', 1954),    ('G', 1992) ,   ('G', 1956)


select min([case]) 'Case', min, mid, max,  count (*) frequency
from (
  select a.[case] [case], min(a.value) min, max(a.value) max, 
         sum(a.value)-min(a.value)-max(a.value) mid
  from @Table1 a      
  group by a.[case]) b
 group by min, mid, max
 order by min([case])
```

Result:

```
Case    min     mid     max     frequency
A       1956    1986    1992    2
B       2000    2001    2003    1
D       2002    2005    2008    1
E       1954    1956    1992    2
```

**EDIT:**
If you only need 4 columns without frequency, this will suffice:

```
 select a.[case] [Case], min(a.value) Value1, 
    sum(a.value)-min(a.value)-max(a.value) Value2,
    max(a.value) Value3         
  from @Table1 a      
  group by a.[case]
```

Result:

```
Case    Value1  Value2  Value3
A       1956    1986    1992
B       2000    2001    2003
C       1956    1986    1992
D       2002    2005    2008
E       1954    1956    1992
G       1954    1956    1992
```

Comment: Thanks Horaciux. This code works perfectly. But Felix Pamittan has a better solution.